# Unity how handle onTouch event?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, events, onclick, ontouch

I add UI object Button and add the C# script with public function.
To button I add component Event Trigger, do events(Pointer Click and Pointer Down) and redirect to my function public void onClick()

On PC code works, but when I upload game to android and touch the object, code not works.

How to do onTouch event?

Answer (score 1):

I think OnMouseDown will check every frame if there is a mouse input it's like update so you have to cheek touch in Update & with touch you will have more control like Touch Phase to detect if the touch begins or lifted or moved etc... 
you need to check

```
 if(input.touchCount > 0)

void Update() {
     if (Input.touchCount > 0){
         print("exist a touch");

             if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began){
                 print("Touch begans");
             }
             if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended){
                 print("Touch Ended");
             }
      }
    }

chCount > 0)& inside this you can cheek for touch Phase
```

Answer (score 0):

## Touches aren't Clicks

In order to handle touch input you need to check [`Input.touchCount`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touchCount.html) and then query each touch with [`Input.GetTouch`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html). Note that each `Touch` has an [an ID](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-fingerId.html) that will be unique per finger and consistent across frames.

There are no easy `OnClick` like methods for touches, as touches can be a lot more complex (tap, long tap, drag, etc), so you will have to check inside `Update()` and handle the conversion from touch data to mouse analogs yourself.

Comment: How I can with Touch detect on which GameObject or UI element user click, move?

Comment: @Cognizer `Physics.Raycast` for GameObjects. Canvas UI elements are already set up to handle touches.